# Move reputation from one website to another website

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Can i move my reputation from one website (like http://meta.stackoverflow.com) to another website(like https://english.stackexchange.com/)?

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: How can do it? can you give more idea please?

Comment: You just need to find somebody who's willing.

Comment: Okay, I have update my question now, thanks dude..

Comment: @devnull , Why you edit that? That's my doubt, please don't remove that dude

Comment: No, the only exception is that if you have 200+ on any site you get 100 rep when you join another site

Comment: You... must... be... kidding...

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't transfer reputation between sites. The reputation you gain on a Stack Exchange site is a rough measure of your participation in that community. If you want reputation on a site, you have to participate there.